# The multi-part identifier "FUNCTION" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, multipart

To a variable I assign a function. This is my error:
The multi-part identifier "APEX.FN_SAV_GENERARCODIGOFORMAPAGO" could not be bound.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE APEX.SP_SAV_INSERTARFORMAPAGO
    @pDescripcion           VARCHAR (50) ,
    @pUsuario               VARCHAR (20) ,
    @pPrograma              VARCHAR (10) ,
    @pOrdenCompra           VARCHAR (10) 
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @pCodigo    VARCHAR (6) 
        SELECT  @pCodigo  = APEX.FN_SAV_GENERARCODIGOFORMAPAGO /*my error*/

        INSERT INTO  APEX.SAV_TIPOS_PAGO   
                  ( COD_TIPO , 
                    DESCRIPCION , 
                    USUARIO_CREA , 
                    PROGRAMA , 
                    ESTADO , 
                    ORDEN_COMPRA )  

         VALUES   ( @pCodigo , 
                    @pDescripcion , 
                    @pUsuario , 
                    @pPrograma , 
                    'A' , 
                    @pOrdenCompra )  

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

    END
```

Comment: Parenthesis missing. `SELECT  @pCodigo  = APEX.FN_SAV_GENERARCODIGOFORMAPAGO()`

Comment: Thanks, I no saw that detail, works to perfection

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @pCodigo = APEX.FN_SAV_GENERARCODIGOFORMAPAGO()
```